# Remove Item of array after getting event value

Tags: arrays, react-native

What I'm trying to get is that, I want to hide or remove item after item selected and moved to another array  with event value, so, it's gonna be like when i move item-1 to  placeholder-2 it should  be removed from placeholder-1 and vice-versa.

Just like it's shown here:

[image]

And this is what I have:

```
const words = [
  { id: 1, word: 'item-1' },
 {...}
];

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [selectedWord, setSelectedWord] = useState([]);
  const [moveSelectedWord, setMoveSelectedWord] = useState([]);

  const handleSelected = (e) => {
    setSelectedWord(e._dispatchInstances.memoizedProps.children);
    setMoveSelectedWord((currentWord) => [...currentWord, selectedWord]);

  };

  const deleteWord = (selectedItem) => {
    setMoveSelectedWord((words) =>
      words.filter((item) => item !== selectedItem)
    );
  };

  return (
    <View
          {moveSelectedWord.map(
            (item) =>
              item.length > 0 && (
                <Text onPress={() => deleteWord(item)} style={styles.text}>
                  {item}
                </Text>
              )
          )}
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
        }}
      >
        {words.map((word, i) => (
          <View
            key={i}
            style={[
              styles.text,
              word.word === selectedWord
                ? styles.hideSelectedText
                : styles.showSelectedText,
            ]}
          >
            <Text onPress={handleSelected}>{word.word}</Text>
          </View>
        ))}
  );
};
```

As you seen I have tried to hide it with style condition, but it won't work properly

Comment: What are you trying to do with `e._dispatchInstances.memoizedProps.children`?

Comment: To get mapped <Text/> value

Answer (score 1):

I am not the most familiar with React-Native but this is how you would do it with React.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const DEFAULT_WORDS = [
    {id: 1, word: 'item-1'},
    {id: 2, word: 'item-2'},
    ...
];

function App() {
    const [words, setWords] = React.useState(DEFAULT_WORDS);
    const setIsSelected = (id, value) => {
        setWords(currentList => {

            return currentList.map((word) => {
                if (id === word.id) {
                    word.isSelected = value;

                }

                return word;
            })
        });
    }
    const MyButton = ({children, isHidden, onClick}) => {

        const style = {
            // opacity: isHidden ? 0 : 1, // Uncomment if you want a placeholder when button is hidden
            // display: isHidden ? "none" : "initial" // Uncomment if you don't want a placeholder 
        }

        return (
            <button 
                onClick={onClick} 
                disabled={isHidden} // Make sure you disable when hidden or transparent for screen readers
                style={style}
            >
                {children}
            </button>
        )

    }

    const selectedWords = words
        .map((word) => (
            <MyButton
                key={word.id}
                word={word}
                isHidden={!word.isSelected}
                onClick={() => setIsSelected(word.id, false)}
            >
                {word.word}
            </MyButton>
        ));

    const unselectedWords = words
        .map((word) => (
            <MyButton
                key={word.id}
                word={word}
                isHidden={word.isSelected}
                onClick={() => setIsSelected(word.id, true)}
            >
                {word.word}
            </MyButton>
        ));

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }} >
                {selectedWords}
            </div>

            <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} >
                {unselectedWords}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I wasn't sure if you wanted a placeholder when the items are clicked but I've shown you how to do it with and without:

#### With a placeholder

```
const style = {
    opacity: isHidden ? 0 : 1
}
```

> [image]
> After clicking item-2

> [image]
> After clicking item-2, item-4, item-12

#### Without a placeholder

```
const style = {
    display: isHidden ? "none" : "initial"
}
```

> [image]
> After clicking item-2

> [image]
> After clicking item-2, item-4, item-12